# Assembly/C/GDB: code to hexadecimal

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, hex

how can I view the hexadecimal representation of some assembler commands?

this is from gdb:

```
0x8048395 <simple+1>            mov    %esp,%ebp
0x8048397 <simple+3>            mov    $0x1,%eax
0x804839c <simple+8>            pop    %ebp                               
0x804839d <simple+9>            ret
```

"simple" is the c function of this program. I tried

```
dump ihex value dump.hex simple
```

which results in

```
:020000040804EE
:0183940000E8
:00000001FF
```

and

```
dump ihex memory dump.hex 0x8048394 0x804839d
```

which results in something different

```
:020000040804EE
:098394005589E5B8010000005D07
:00000001FF
```

why are they different? is one of them correct?

Comment: I don't know which is correct, but you could always just use `objdump`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see the real bytes you can simply use:

```
disas /r simple
```

Of if you want to dump to a file to raw binary

```
dump binary memory file.bin 0x8048394 0x804839d
```

The `ihex` format is the [**Intel Hex format**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX), and it is not as straightforward as it may seem.

Also, when you use `dump value` you are dumping the value of the address of the function, not the code of the function itself. That is what is done with `dump memory`.

**UPDATE**: Actually, when you do `dump <format> value dump.hex simple`, it dumps the content of `simple`, but not knowing how to dump a function value, it dumps it as if it were a `char` value, that is, it dumps the first byte of the function. If you want to dump the address of the function, just do: `dump <format> value dump.hex &simple`.